# Formdata is empty

Tags: jquery

i am trying to send some jpg files using jquery but the formdata comes empty

here is the html

```
<input id="fileUpload" multiple="multiple" type="file"/> 
 <ul>
 <li><div id="image-holder"></div></li>
 <li><input type="submit" value="Next"></li>
</ul>
```

here is the script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#submit').click(function() {  

    var files = $("[type='file']")[0].files;

    var formdata = new FormData();

    $.each(files, function(key, value)
    {
        console.log(value)
        formdata.append('file-'+key, value);
        console.log(formdata)
    });

    $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            data: { 'formdata' : formdata , csrfmiddlewaretoken:'{{csrf_token}}'},
            url : "{% url 'data_entry' %}",
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            success: function(data) {  
            },
            error: function(response, error) {
        }
    });
}); 
</script>
```

this is what i get when i console the formdata `FormData {}` why is the formdata empty?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`FormData` object should not be empty. You can use [`FormData.get()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/get) to retrieve value stored at named key within `FormData` object. Note also `#submit` element does not appear at `html`; if you are trying to select `<input type="submit">` element, you can use selector `$("input[type=submit]").click(handler)`

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="fileUpload" multiple="multiple" type="file" />
<ul>
  <li>
    <div id="image-holder"></div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <input type="submit" value="Next">
  </li>
</ul>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $("input[type=submit]").click(function() {

    var files = $("[type='file']")[0].files;

    var formdata = new FormData();

    $.each(files, function(key, value) {
      formdata.append("file-" + key, value);
      console.log(formdata.get("file-" + key))
    });

  });
</script>
```